# C++ Easy way to ignore first word of input

Tags: c++, vector, io, getline

I am writing a program to read a text file line by line, store the line values in a vector, do some processing then write back to a new text file. This is what the text file typically looks like:

[image]

As you can see, there are two columns: one for the frame number and another for the time. What I want is only the second column (aka the time). There can be hundreds, if not thousands of lines in the text file. Previously I have been manually deleting the frame number column which i'd rather not do. So my question is: is there an easy way to edit my current code so that when I read the file with `getline()` it skips the first word and only gets the second? Here is the code that I use to read the text file. Thanks

```
ifstream sysfile(sys_time_dir);

//Store lines in a vector
vector<string> sys_times;
string textline;

while (getline(sysfile, textline))
{
    sys_times.push_back(textline);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string ignore_me;
while (sysfile >> ignore_me, getline(sysfile, textline)) {
...
```

This utilizes the comma operator, reading in the first word (here defining "word" as a continuous sequence of non-space characters) of the line, but ignoring the result, then using `getline` to read the rest of the line.

Note that for the specific data format you describe, I would rather choose what RSahu showed in their answer. My answer is more general to the problem of *"skipping the first word and reading the rest of the line"*.

Comment: Is there any benefit to using comma rather than `&&` here?

Comment: @molbdnilo: Nope. Other than subjectively further clarifying that I don't care about the success of the first operation. Also, for someone like me, who has to sometimes look up operator precedence, I at least can always remember that the comma operator is the lowest precedence.

Comment: FWIW, if the desire is to read `textline` without leading whitespace, `sysfile >> ignore_me >> std::ws` can be used....

Answer (score 7):

Since you have two numbers in each line, you can read two numbers and ignore the first number.

```
vector<double> sys_times;
int first;
double second;
while ( sysfile >> first >> second )
{
   sys_times.push_back(second);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yours worked as well but unfortunately I can't accept 2 answers

Comment: @oodan123, not a problem at all.